# CRUD methods with PHP, JS/jQuery, and a little AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, sqlite

I've been working on a system where you can create-read-update-delete to/from a table in a SQLite database.  So far I've only written the create and view methods (easy).

Now, I have ran into a roadblock on deciding how to go about deleting and updating items.  On the view page, there is query to the database through php and a generation of the table (echoed through php into html).  There is also a button added next to each row that looks like a little trash can to delete the row.

How can I use AJAX to simultaneously delete the row from the html table and sqlite table?  A more definitive question would be, how can I link each button to each row and query the database when the button is clicked?

Here is the generated table:

```
foreach($result as $entry){
 echo  '<tr>' . '<td>'. $entry['department']. ' ' . $entry['CRN']. '</td>' . 
    '<td>'. $entry['title'] . '</td>' . 
    '<td>'. $entry['addDate'] . '</td>'. 
    '<td><button class="fg-button fg-button-icon-left ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span></button></td>'.'</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a PHP controller and action.  It has to take an ID as a parameter and it should execute a delete command against your database using that ID.  Ideally, it will accept only DELETE requests (not GET or POST).  This isn't always possible because some browsers don't support DELETE HTTP requests.
2. on your front end, create HTML and javascript that looks like this:

HTML:

```
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Delete Button" data-rowId="12"/>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#clickMe').click(function(){
        // send the delete request
        $.ajax({
            url: '/myEntity/delete',
            data: {id: $(this).data('rowId')},
            type: 'DELETE',
            // removes the row only if the delete succeeds
            success: function(){ $(this).parents('tr').remove(); }
        });
    });
});
```

Change type: 'DELETE' to type: 'POST' if you're working with browsers that don't support DELETE.

Comment: a delete request is possible through js? so instead of .post() it would be something like .delete()?

Comment: @TrevorMA: Yes, DELETE can be used (as with the other HTTP verbs) here, but may not be supported by all browsers.

Comment: Well, it's not JS.  GET, POST, and DELETE are kinds of HTTP requests.  Ajax is just an asynchronous HTTP request mechanism.  Above, I'm using jQuery to show how you can do a DELETE.  Now, in jQuery, $.post and $.get are just shorthands for $.ajax({ ... type: 'POST' ... }) or $.ajax({ ... type: 'GET' ... }).  There is no shorthand for DELETE so you have to use the syntax I showed you.  This is useful because DELETE can't get accidentally hit by spiders, etc.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @Demian: Man, this site is brutal! So hard to get good answers out there first, people must type like 150 wpm.  Anyway, thanks for the +1.

Comment: @Milimetric Agreed, however you'd be amazed at some of the lack of thought that go into a LOT of answers that people leave just so that they get it answered first ;)

Comment: @Milimetric Can data-rowID be put in a <button>?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.  I dont think you can put the rowid in the button

Comment: data-rowId is not a standard HTML attribute, it's just the convention that jQuery uses to add data to HTMLElement(s).  So you can add data-anyPropertyYouWant="something" on any html tag and then read it in with $('select-that-tag').data('anyPropertyYouWant');  If you want, you can also set it from javascript.  Just take a look at jQuery data: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: @Milimetric It works...but only for the first row, and still it doesn't remove the row using ajax. i have to manually refresh.

Comment: @TrevorMA - put it up in jsfiddle, let us check it out

Answer (score 0):

You could have the Ajax call return the new list of values and just replace the entire table with the new content.

- In the JS, make delete call with a callback.
- In the callback:

  - empty the `div` that contains the
    table
  - create a new table based on the
    results of the call (by making a call to PHP if that's what's generating the table)
  - append that table
    to the `div`

That's something we do often, although, we need to since it's a multi-user system.

Comment: Re-creating the table seems to incur a lot of unneeded overhead when you can simply remove the row.

Comment: @TrevorMA, a callback is reference to a function that you can then pass around to other methods, in this case, to the ajax call, so that it will call your function when it completes.

Comment: @Demian Brecht, it's overhead, yes, but as I stated in my answer, in a multi-user system, it will provide the most accurate content.  If the results are time-critical, you would be polling the back-end regularly for new content anyway, so the code to replace the table would already be written.  It all depends on the requirements, I suppose.